# Setting a parameter in Post body to header when accessing Get endpoint in Flask?

Tags: python, http, flask

I am working on a simple service with my show_greeting endpoint handling Get request while set_greeting is my Post.
The purpose of this app is that when "header_message: {header parameter}" is sent to set_greeting, {header parameter} will be returned in the header for responses to show_greeting and to reset {header parameter}, "clear" would reset header_message and header.

I have tried using global variables but encountered an error with shadowing from outside the scope and am not sure which approach to take for this.  For now, I would like to learn how to return {header parameter} from my /show_greeting endpoint.

Edit: The /show_greeting endpoint returns holiday_message from the request.  The header that I would like to send in addition to holiday_message is "header_message".

My code is as follows:

```
from flask import Flask, request, make_response, Response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/show_greeting', methods=['GET'])
def show_greeting():
    received = request.args    
    (I do not know how to set header here from header_message in set_greeting)
    return received['holiday_message']


@app.route('/set_greeting', methods=['POST'])
def set_greeting():
    posted = request.args
    if 'header_message' in posted:
        (I attempted save_message = posted['header_message'] here but this approach failed)
        return "Header Message Set"
    else:
        return "Please Send A Header Message"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: I think you should familiarize yourself with [sessions](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/#sessions) in order to save data. Global variables work too, but are not a good approach.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to use the [session](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/#sessions) object. It stores the data in a cookie, which is sent with every request.
If a cookie is not desired, there are other options for saving sessions. For this, however, an extension will be necessary.

Saving with global variables should also work, but is not recommended.
A file or a database can also be used if the data is to be saved across multiple requests from many users.

The data of the post body can be accessed via [`request.form`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.Request.form), while the url parameters of a get request can be queried via [`request.args`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.Request.args).

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request, session

app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = b'your secret here'

@app.route('/show_greeting', methods=['GET'])
def show_greeting():
    received = request.args
    # get the saved message or an empty string if no message is saved
    header_message = session.get('header_message', '')
    return f"{received['holiday_message']} - {header_message}"

@app.route('/set_greeting', methods=['POST'])
def set_greeting():
    posted = request.form
    if 'header_message' in posted:
        # store the message 
        session['header_message'] = posted['header_message']
        return "Header Message Set"
    else:
        # clear the message 
        session.pop('header_message', None)
        return "Please Send A Header Message"
```

Much success in your further steps.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem, you can work with "g" the flask global object.

Check this code, I expect it will fix your issue.

```
from flask import g # Added

from flask import Flask, request, make_response, Response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/show_greeting', methods=['GET'])
def show_greeting():
    received = request.args    
    return g.saved_message # Modified


@app.route('/set_greeting', methods=['POST'])
def set_greeting():
    posted = request.args
    if 'message' in posted:

        g.saved_message = posted['request'] # Added

        return "Message Set"
    else:
        return "Please Send A Greeting Message"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: Hello, I tested using g.saved_message with Postman but the get request was returning that saved_message was not found.

Comment: @RikoKurahashi The g object is intended to store data within a request, but not to store data across multiple requests. Look [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/appcontext/#storing-data).

Comment: @Detlef I see, so then would it be valid to do g.saved_message = posted['request'] in my POST endpoint then in my GET endpoint, resp = make_response(g.pop('request', None)) followed by resp.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*' ?

Edit: I tried it by received error that the function did not return a valid response.

Comment: @RikoKurahashi You cannot save data in the g object across multiple queries. It saves data in the application context, which is only valid for a single request, regardless of whether it is GET or POST.

Comment: @Detlef Thank you for the clarification.  I have added sessions with the secret key but the issue I am running into now is that I do not see the Post body message in my Get endpoint header.